# Windows 10 "ghost files", cannot be removed even by admin

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems

When I try to remove files, they sometimes become "ghost files" that are impossible to delete. These files disappear when the computer is restarted, but restarting my computer isn't always a reasonable solution because of rendering or other long-running tasks. Programs which frequently create and remove files (such as programs using lock files) often stop working because of these ghost files they cannot remove or replace. No program can open the file, either.

File Access Denied when I try to remove the  file:

[image: File Access Denied when I try to remove the file]

Security Settings when I right click the file:

[image: Security Settings when I right click the file]

This is a daily problem. How can I either fix Windows so that these ghost files won't show up, or manually remove them without rebooting when they show up?

Clarifications (EDIT):

- My user has administrator privileges.
- This isn't related to any single program, it just happens randomly and not every time. It tends to happen when I do things where files are frequently removed and then replaced with another one of the same name (using node packet manager, compiling C++ code in Visual Studio, etc).
- I keep the files I work with in a normal directory tree directly under the C:/ drive, they are not in a user folder or any other protected location.

Comment: Are you admin on your computer???

Comment: @EricF I am an admin, all admin commands work normally (except for removing the file).

Comment: It looks that the problem is linked to Dell Data Protection Encryption feature ??? If this is the case, you could think about uninstall it...

Comment: @Maxwell77 It is a self-built desktop so there shouldn't be any Dell features. I do not have any encryption enabled.

Comment: If you run Process Explorer as Admin. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer - Find - Find handle or dll and search for the file, does it show up?

Comment: You need to first identify which program or service is creating those files.  Once you do that, update your question, to provide the relevant information

Comment: @Ramhound I have seen it happen with many different filetypes created by many unrelated programs. It doesn't seem to be related to any single program or service.

Comment: sshpk-conv seems to be an ubuntu (linux) file?...http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/sshpk-conv.1.html

Comment: @Moab The file in the screenshots was created by npm running in docker so that is why it is a linux file. But I have had the same problem happen .exe files compiled with Visual Studio, so I don't think it is related to docker.

Comment: @Steve I have witnessed this sort of problem in the past and in one instance of it, I was able to remove the files after killing `explorer.exe` and then restarting it. From an admin elevated command prompt, type in `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` and press **Enter**. Then in that same command prompt type in `explorer` and press **Enter**. Now try to delete the files. If that works, let me know and I'll make as an official answer. I assume you are going to stick around and not suddenly disappear after your first question asked, right? You can get lots of help for many things here btw.

Comment: This directory is contained with your user profile directory?  I can’t tell if that’s the case.  This bit of information is vital.  Where are these other files, which cannot be deleted, locates exactly?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks for sharing, when the problem happens again I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @Ramhound I have one big folder on the C:/ drive and the files are in different subfolders under that. No user directories or other special permissions are involved.

Comment: The root directory of a system drive in Windows requires escalating any process trying to write to it.  What is odd is the screenshots indicate your user isn’t the owner, and even the Administrator group, isn’t in the ACL.

Comment: Who is listed as the owner, and what happens when you try to take ownership?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any workaround @Steve ?

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same thing today.
We also have IIS, but restarting did not fix it.

In our case someone still had a SMB handle on the file. I resolved it by going to

mmc -> Shared folders -> Open files

and manually closing the connection, which was still accessing the file.

Comment: And fyi the Process Explorer handle showed "System"

Answer (score -1):

We have just experienced this issue. It was mind boggling, but it ended up that IIS was still holding onto the files. After we have restarted IIS we were able to delete the files that we wanted to delete. As HelpingHand recommended, figure out which app might still has the handle on the file(s). Good luck!

[image]
[image]