# Locked or ghost file created when a file is moved or deleted

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-management, vbscript

When a commercial software package has processed a file in location A, it moves it to location B (from the changes to the file attributes, I suspect that it writes the data from A to B & deletes from A, rather than using a move command, but I am not sure).  I have no control over what it does.  I have a VBScript running, checking for & further interrogating unprocessed files in location A.

The issue is that occasionally the file appears to exist in locations A & B after processing (we are probably talking <0.01% of the time - certainly less than any code issue is likely to create, so probably caused by system/network conditions at the time of the move/delete).  The file in the destination, folder B appears to be 'normal', i.e. functionally no different to any other file in location B.  The file left in location A on the rare occasion appears to be 'super-locked' - no one even those with full admin rights to location A can do anything to it (open, rename, move, delete, delete parent folder, etc.).  It does have attributes, indeed comparing the details tab within properties in Windows, I noticed that the owner attribute is not shown for the file in location A, but is for the one in location B.  This is why I think it could be a 'ghost file', more technically a spurious record in the MFT.

The VBS crashes when it tries to process (which includes an open for reading) the file in location A.  Once the servers reboot at the weekend, the file no longer appears in location A & the VBS starts completing again.

Can anyone suggest what is happening, why & is there a way to identify the file in the VBS (thus avoiding trying to process it/falling over)?  Apologies if this is not in the correct section.

EDIT: Thanks @harrymc - I do not believe that the issue occurs at a time when the files would be subject to virus scan (on creation or on schedule) - still good to know that the idea of a ghost file is not laughable.

EDIT: Thanks @harrymc - I do not have the privilege here to post comments, so this thread remaining is good for me.  My colleagues (those with admin privileges) have ran process explorer, but said (I have never seen the program, so I hope this makes sense) that it did not provide the name of a process that was locking the file.  I have resorted to logging the name of the file before interrogating, clearing it after, then checking on run to see if a log remains (i.e. the name of a ghost file) & skipping that file.

Comment: I have seen this kind of ghosts appear when the antivirus decided to keep these files semi-alive while scanning them. You could use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to search for a process using this file. You could also try to disable the antivirus as a test.

Comment: I have just found a question which appears to be the same (or similar enough) - can this be closed (it may be worth keeping rather than deleting to direct others). https://superuser.com/questions/1332667/windows-10-ghost-files-cannot-be-removed-even-by-admin?rq=1

Comment: The other question has no answers, so you may keep this post. Has Process Explorer found anything?

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, we think we know what is happening (NOT why/how to prevent it) - I would not believe this had I not seen it:  we download the files from a commercial cloud storage service, everything can move & read the file, but even though it has been moved since downloading, if the web browser session (note not just the tab, the window) is still open, the file will not delete cleanly.  I have seen this happen & further proved that closing the browser window made the ghost file disappear. I could understand were it not for the file having been moved by another program!

Comment: I just hope your browser is not infected.